# How to preview chinese HTML/XML file in Alfresco 4.0.d?

Tags: alfresco, preview

I couldn't preview Chinese HTML/XML file which are created from '/share' application. but Chinese TXT file is well and normal.
The chinese content of three kinds of files are well and normal, except preview for TXT file. chinese enoding can't be display correctly.

for HTML,
when I define the text contents with some special fonts in editior, preview will be ok.
seems that if you don't define the fonts for whole HTML file text content, Alfresco won't find any fonts to preview it,Chinese characters will be garbled.

But for XML,
I can't define text fonts with no entry.

I tried to debug this with these article : http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Content_Transformation_Debug
And add
log4j.logger.org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.TransformerDebugsmileyEBUG

into files:
tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties

But there was not any effects!
Any help would be appreciated

-----My ENV
Centos OS 5
mysql5
tomcat6
Alfresco:4.2

Comment: Are you sure the files have been uploaded with the correct encoding?

Comment: I wrote the HTML/XML file throught web page of Alfresco Share, not uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post will help:

http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/configuration/preview-missing-chinese

> I copied the files "simhei.tff" and "simsun.ttc" to
>   /opt/bitnami/libreoffice/share/fonts/truetype and after the font cache
>   was refreshed (restart) it works like a charm.